# Insert .xml file containing word document into mysql using php script

Tags: php, mysql, xml, excel, upload

I wrote this code for Inserting Excel (.xml) file into `MySQL`  database using `PHP` Script.
But It cannot inserting data containing MS.WORD (TABLE, PICTURES, etc.), there is a inserting of blank space instead of Word Document.
    
                
                    &nbsp Upload Questions

```
             <div style="float: left;">
            <table>
                    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="post">
                      <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="2000000" />
                            <tr>
                            <td><h5><b>Select Standared</b></h5></td>
                            <td><select name="chap_sel_std" id="chap_sel_std">
                                                        <option>Select Standared</option>
                                                <?php
                                                    $exe_sel_std = mysql_query("SELECT * from s_standared");
                                                    while($r_sel_std = mysql_fetch_array($exe_sel_std)){
                                                        $sel_stdid = $r_sel_std['std_id'];
                                                        $sel_std = $r_sel_std['std'];?>

                                                        <option value="<?php echo $sel_stdid; ?>"><?php echo $sel_std;?></option>
                                                        <?php } ?>
                                </select></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><h5><b>Select Font</b></h5></td>
                                <td><select name="sel_f_gn_que">
                                    <option>Select Font</option>
                                        <?php
                                            $xf = mysql_query("SELECT * from s_font");
                                            while($rquef = mysql_fetch_array($xf)){
                                                $f_id = $rquef['f_id'];
                                                $f_name = $rquef['f_name'];  ?>
                                    <option value="<?php echo $f_id; ?>"><?php echo $f_name; }?>  </option>
                                </select></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><h5><b>Upload Question<h5><b></td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" class="">
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td></td>
                                <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" class="btn btn-green big" name="add_que" value="Add Questions"></td>
                                <td><input type="submit" name="saveandexit" class="btn btn-blue" value="Finish and close Me" onclick="close();"></td>
                            </tr>
                    </form>
                    </table>
                    </div>                   

    <?php

            $data = array();

    //$db =& DB::connect("mysql://root@localhost/names", array());
    //if (PEAR::isError($db)) { die($db->getMessage()); }
      //quetype    difficulty    standard    subject    chap    que    marks

    function add_person($quetype,$dif, $subject,$chap_name,$que,$marks)
    {
     global $data, $db;

     //$sth = $db->prepare( "INSERT INTO names VALUES( 0, ?, ?, ?, ? )" );
    // $db->execute( $sth, array( $first, $middle, $last, $email ) );

     $data []= array(
       'quetype' => $quetype, 
       'difficulty' => $dif,
       'subject' => $subject,
       'chap' => $chap_name,
       'que' => $que,
       //'ans' => $ans,
       'marks' => $marks

     );
    }

    if(!isset($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])){
        echo "";
    }elseif($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])
    {
     $dom = DOMDocument::load( $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] );
     $rows = $dom->getElementsByTagName( 'Row' );
     $first_row = true;
     foreach ($rows as $row)
     {
       if ( !$first_row )
       {
         $quetype = "";
         $dif = "";
         $subject = "";
         $chap_name = "";
         $que = "";
         //$ans = "";
         $marks = "";

         $index = 1;
         $cells = $row->getElementsByTagName( 'Cell' );
         foreach( $cells as $cell )
         {
           $ind = $cell->getAttribute( 'Index' );
           if ( $ind != null ) $index = $ind;

           if ( $index == 1 ) $quetype = $cell->nodeValue;
           if ( $index == 2 ) $dif = $cell->nodeValue;
           if ( $index == 4 ) $subject = $cell->nodeValue;
           if ( $index == 6 ) $chap_name = $cell->nodeValue;
           if ( $index == 8) $que = $cell->nodeValue;
           //if ( $index == 9) $ans = $cell->nodeValue;
           if ( $index == 9) $marks = $cell->nodeValue;

           $index += 1;
         }
         add_person($quetype,$dif, $subject,$chap_name,$que,$marks);

         if(isset($_POST['add_que'])){    

                 $chap_sel_std = $_POST['chap_sel_std'];
                 echo $simquefnt = $_POST['sel_f_gn_que'];

                    //que_id    quetype_id    chap_id    sub_id    std_id    que    dif_id    marks    que_cdate
             //$chap_sel_std = $_POST['chap_sel_std']; //que_id    quetype_id    chap_id    sub_id    std_id    que    dif_id    marks    que_cdate
             mysql_query("INSERT INTO 
                          s_question
                          VALUES (null,'$quetype','$chap_name','$subject','$chap_sel_std',N'$que','NO IMAGE','$dif','$marks','$simquefnt','$current')");                                                        
    //         header("location:../admin/quetionaris.php#tabs-que"); 
         echo "Successfully Added";
          }
       }
       $first_row = false;
     }
    }
    ?>
    </body>                 
</html>
```

Comment: what is the field that stores ms word data? Show its data type.

Comment: "Inserting Excel (.xml) file" . Excel OR XML

Comment: field name is, "N'$que'" (  que  text  utf8_general_ci   No  None  )

Answer (score 1):

You really need to learn how to escape the data when putting them into an SQL query.

Learn about SQL injections. They make your databases and applications accessible openly to anyone.

And then finally use `mysql_escape_string`.

Comment: I have already read this topic SQL Injection, and also used Collation :- "utf8_general_ci" but the main problem is that I can't able to Insert Images OR Equation into .xml file

Comment: You did not understand it. Find out what `mysql_escape_string` has to do with SQL injection.